# Logical AND statement

Tags: c

Is this statement correct in C-language?

```
a && b && c
```

I want to check `((a==2) && (b==3) && (c==4))`.Is this usage of logical `AND` correct?

Comment: Have you *tried* or searched Google?!

Comment: `((a==2) && (b==3) && (c==4))` is perfectly valid usage of logical AND operations.

Comment: @SamuraiJack `a && b && c` checks whether each value is not equal to 0.

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct'?

Comment: The logical AND operator groups left-to-right, so `a && b && c` is equivalent to `(a && b) && c`.  That should completely answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the usage is correct. You can AND as many expressions as you want.